# Rails form_with results in a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm re-building a blog from the ground up and a ran into a problem concerning the form for creating new articles.

`<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>` results in the error `` undefined method `form_with' ``.

Rails provides the following suggestion:
`Did you mean?  form_tag`

Upon trying `form_tag`, I get the following error: `` undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass ``

**Form for new article using form_with**

```
<h1>New Blog Post</h1>
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @articles = Article.all 
    end

    def show
       @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

When I change `form_with` to `form_tag` I get the following error: `` undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass ``

For the record, I'm using

1. Ruby 2.3.4
2. Rails 4.2.5

Comment: Form_with has been introduced in rails 5 (5.1 ?) use form_for with the correct syntax in rails 4

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `form_for @article do |form|` ([`form_for` Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.9/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), `form_tag` is used when you want a form tag (HTML tag) that's not necessarily attached to a ActiveRecord object.