# NoMethodError in Articles#new in form_for using Rails 4.2.5 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

I am trying to complete the official Rails tutorial and on step 5.2. The instructions are to do a form_with, but i got an error, looked up this StackOverflow post:
[Rails form_with results in a NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431227/rails-form-with-results-in-a-nomethoderror). I changed the `form_with` to `form_for` like the answer said, and i get this error:

#### NoMethodError in Articles#new

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

`undefined method 'model_name' for {:scope=>:article, :url=>"/articles", :local=>true}:Hash`

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1. <h1>New Article</h1>
2. <%= form_for scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
3.   <p>
4.     <%= form.label :title %><br>
5.     <%= form.text_field :title %>
6.   </p>
```

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

`app/views/articles/new.html.erb:2:in '_app_views_articles_new_html_erb__1707235537542743350_40377020'`

I am using Cloud9, if it helps. Here is my code for the view and controller:
View:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    render plain: params[:article].inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought your `ArticleController` would look like:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    render plain: params[:article].inspect
  end
end
```

And your view would look like:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for @article do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Given an `@article`, `form_for` will correctly infer the url as long as:

> the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in config/routes.rb

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

It is also worth noting, perhaps, that the signature for `form_for` is (again, according to the docs):

> form_for(record, options = {}, &block)

Which means that `form_for` expects to be passed (1) a record, (2) zero or more options, and (3) a block. A 'record' can actually be one of a number of things (such as an instance, a string, or a symbol), as described in the docs.

When you do:

```
<%= form_for scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

I believe what is going on is that `form_for` is accepting the hash `{scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true}` as the record and attempting to infer the url by calling `model_name` on the hash. A hash, naturally, does not respond to `model_name`, and so you get:

```
undefined method 'model_name' for {:scope=>:article, :url=>"/articles", :local=>true}:Hash
```

Comment: i know the create action won't do anything _yet_. im just following the tutorial

Comment: if it helps, the link to the guide is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not that into studying the guide right now. But, do give the above a shot and see if it helps things along.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running an older version of Rails. On the command line run `rails -v` and make sure it's the same version as the tutorial you are reading.